# Error when using @TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) with remote EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, glassfish, ejb

When uses TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER instead of TransactionManagementType.BEAN in my remote EJB i got the exception:

> javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.SecurityException
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2115)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2078)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy279.listar(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1550)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1426)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:931)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:695)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:497)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2223)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
>   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
>       at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.rollback(TransactionManagerImpl.java:376)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.rollbackDistributedTransaction(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:219)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.rollback(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:892)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.destroyBeanAndRollback(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:578)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:701)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4600)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2108)
>       ... 21 more

According to the specification I believe this operation is possible (Control the transaction by the client) and for me the only plausible reason to use remote EJB.

About the bug, I ran tests locally using two glassfish servers, all ports are released, and in the glassfish owning the server application, the config orb-listener-1 has "security" checkbox not checked..

I will describe a code below by examining the core of the server and client applications:

This code block runs on my server:

```
package br.com;
@Remote
interface IRemote {void method();}

@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
class Remote implements IRemote { 

void method(){
    executeMyBusinessLogic
}
```

And this code block runs in an app on my local machine:

```
@Stateless
class LocalBean {
    @EJB(mappedName = "corbaname:iiop:myserver.com:3700#java:global/RemoteApp/Remote!br.com.IRemote"
    private IRemote remote;

    @Transactional
    void testMethod(){remote.method();}
}
```

When invoke testMethod i got the exception above.

**If i use TransactionManagementType.BEAN and remove `@TransactionAttribute` it will works but it's not what I want.**
**I want to control transaction in the client application.**

I'm using Glassfish 5 and java EE specification 8.0

**UPDATE 1:**
Looking at Server application log, this message occurs after the client invokation;

> [2017-12-05T12:13:33.379-0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [jts.exception_in_register_synchronization] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.jta] [tid: _ThreadID=99 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 2] [timeMillis: 1512483213379] [levelValue: 900] [[
>     JTS5071: Unexpected error occurred in registerSynchronization
>   org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: DETALHADO: 00410008: Connection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy237.connectionAbort(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrategy(ConnectionImpl.java:1287)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.doWork(ConnectionImpl.java:845)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
>   Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: DETALHADO: 00410011: IOException received when reading from connection SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl[ java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/192.168.25.10:55856 remote=dell-henrique.home/192.168.25.10:49] ESTABLISHED true true]  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11  completed: No
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy237.ioexceptionWhenReadingConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(ConnectionImpl.java:1465)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrategy(ConnectionImpl.java:1241)
>       ... 3 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: End-of-stream
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(ConnectionImpl.java:1458)
>       ... 4 more
>   ]]

Comment: perhaps [markmail](http://markmail.org/message/nglt37iumgnpn62u#query:+page:1+mid:7ehlaekdixx3jlyo+state:results) helps perhaps there is also an exception: org.omg.CORBA.INVALID_TRANSACTION occurring before that SecurityException

Comment: It's occur CORBA.COMM_FAILURE on server application log. I updated the question.

Comment: Could you try out what happens, if you annotate Remote with TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED instead of REQUIRED and handle the real RemoteTransactions inside a local delegate of Remote?

Comment: Thanks for help! I have news:
I have cleanup my workspace and glassfish instalation. After this all this errors didn't happen. I can use Transaction Management by Container but without client transaction involved. The problem now is that when i use Transacion in both sides, The communication freezes for ever when i invoke the server method in client. In other words, when i use TransactionAttribute on server and when i involve my client with a transaction context and invoke the server method, **this invokation never ends...** I neeed to stop servers and kill process that listens my IIOOP port.

Comment: UPDATE:

`Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: ADVERTÊNCIA: 00410019: Communications timeout waiting for response.  Exceeded 1.800.000 milliseconds  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 19 completed: Maybe
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO ABC (NOME) VALUES (?)
 bind => [JOTAJOTA]`

Comment: I'm using Mysql Database with resource type "javax.sql.XADataSource" and datasource class name "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource"